# Writing REST API Query For Zapier ForPublic API

Tags: rest, get, zapier

I am trying to write a query to get only the volume data from https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries into Zapier.

I tried: https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries?fields=[volume] and a number of other queries put it still loads all of the information.

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It doesn't seem to support querying like that, so you likely need to do something with the data before you pass it to zapier. https://cryptowat.ch/docs/api#summaries

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like Cryptowatch supports querying like that as @denmch said. That said, you might want to explain your use case here to answer this better.

It is possible to run a code step (Use Code by Zapier) to filter out just the fields you need.

```js
fetch('https://api.cryptowat.ch/markets/summaries')
    .then(function(res) {
        return res.text();
    }).then(function(body) {
        var pBody = JSON.parse(body).result;
        var keys = Object.keys(pBody);
        keys.push('volume', 'volumeQuote');
        var output = JSON.stringify(pBody, keys, 2);
        callback(null, output);
    }).catch(callback);
```

The output of the above code will be like so,

```json
{
  "binance:adabtc": {
    "volume": 176172110,
    "volumeQuote": 3774.9155
  },
  "binance:adaeth": {
    "volume": 28468302,
    "volumeQuote": 10073.711
  }
}
```

**Note:** The Zap will timeout in 1 sec if you do not have a paid account. If the cryptowatch server takes long to respond, this above step will fail on a free Zapier account.

Comment: I am trying to get volume for each exchange for each currency pair, I will work with what you suggested and see if I can get that to work. Thank you

Comment: @racheal-brooker You might want to explore creating an [app](https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/) on Zapier.

If this answer solved your problem, make sure to upvote it and select it as correct [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)